# Full Oracle backup from PHP

Tags: php, oracle, oracle9i, oracle-call-interface

I maintain a PHP driven web application with Oracle backend. The app interacts with a number of third-party apps so information is managed with a combination of XML files, Microsoft Access databases and HTML forms. There are currently 80 tables with many BLOBs and a pretty good bunch of foreign key relationships. All procedures are carefully explained in a document that (of course) nobody ever reads. The customer was feeling uneasy about his data so he was given an estimate with some improvements that could be made (stuff like adding previews and confirmations in some operations).

Sadly, the customer misinterpreted one of the specs (a partial export to be written in 12 man-hours) and he's expecting a full backup and restore feature that would allow him to save and restore the complete database through a web browser without the DBA intervention.

Before having yet another argument with the client, I'd like to know whether I have any option to actually implement this feature in a timely manner, considering that it doesn't need any refinements (e.g., there is no need to select what to restore).

Production server is a Windows Server 2003 box running PHP/5.2.9. The Oracle server is a remote box running "Oracle9i Release 9.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production".

*(Please note I'm not a DBA so there may be well-known solutions I'm not aware of.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle is a monster. Once [you've read this](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Oracle_database_Backup_and_Recovery_FAQ) you'll realise that how you backup the system depends totally on how it has been configured. The short answer is to automate whatever manual process - invoke it as a long running process (since this is MSWindows, prefix the rman command with 'start') then use polling to detect when it finishes (e.g. wrap rman in a DOS batch file which logs start and end times).

I'd be hard pushed to think of a more difficult problem to provide a generic solution for than Oracle runing on top of MSWindows. The latter may be nice for users to click on buttons, but automating *anything* is a PITA.

Have fun :)

Comment: Oh my... It all points to yet-another-argument-with-the-client. I'll use the 12 hours just reading the FAQ `:-P`. Whatever, thank you for the link. It's way more clear than the official Oracle docs I could find.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I had the chance of implementing full Oracle backup from PHP in a later project. I used the [Oracle Data Pump](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/10g/oracle-data-pump-10g.php) command-line utilities, available since 10g. In short:

1. You define an Oracle directory to map a keyword to a physical directory and grant write permission to the app's Oracle user.
2. You run `expdp` with the appropriate arguments and get a complete dump in a single file.
3. To restore a backup, you run `impdp`.

It's also advisable to run commands with [proc_open()](http://php.net/proc_open) rather than [system()](http://php.net/system) since you can `bypass_shell` if on Windows and have fine-grained control on the process.

As for this question, the pre-10g alternative is the "exp" / "imp" combo.